# Azure Handler mappings, how to point an extention to .net 4.5?

Tags: azure, iis, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Website setup, and I'm trying to point .html to .net 4.5 because I want MVC to route the request for the extension, and I believe that IIS is routing it and it's never making it to mvc/asp.net to decide where to go.

There is a Handler Mappings section, but I'm not sure what to put for the script processor path.

Comment: What exactly do you want to "point .html to .net 4.5"? Use URL Rewrite module should help in most cases to convert .html to .aspx or whatever your ASP.NET app expects.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I guess you can map it to System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory

Answer (score 0):

The Script Processor value should be "The absolute path to the FastCGI application." [More details found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/getconfiguration#handlermapping)

Answer (score 0):

Settings -> Configuration -> Path Mappings
The ScriptProcessor will be reference to one of the available handler mappings installed on IIS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/handlers/

If you want to see the available Script mappings then you can do this.

1. Go to the App Services Portal
2. Open App Service for Windows
3. Click 'Go' under Advanced Tools
4. In Kudu go to Debug Console
5. Find and open ApplicationHost.config.

You’ll see some examples under there.

```
  <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script">

    <add name="PHP56_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" />

    <add name="svc-ISAPI-2.0-64" path="*.svc" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness64" />

    <add name="svc-ISAPI-2.0" path="*.svc" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv2.0,bitness32" />

    <add name="svc-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*.svc" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" />

    <add name="svc-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*.svc" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" />

    <add name="svc-Integrated-4.0" path="*.svc" verb="*" type="System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpHandlerFactory, System.ServiceModel.Activation, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />

    <add name="ASPClassic" path="*.asp" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" resourceType="File" />
```